# Return boolean type in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am using `ST_Intersects()` to know whether two geometries intersect or not.
This is my code:

```
$var_name = pg_query($conn,"SELECT ST_Intersects(p1.column_name, 
p2.column_name)
FROM table_name AS p1, table_name AS p2
WHERE p1.id < p2.id");
if(pg_fetch_assoc($var_name) == 'false')
{
echo "accepted";
}
else
{
echo "rejected";
}
```

I know that the geometries are not intersecting and when I run the same query in Postgres the result is `false` as expected.

But here it is executing the `else` statement. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Among other things, I'd bet Postgres returns the boolean `false`, not the string `'false'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erwin's advice is (as always) good, but in your particular case I think the problem is in your test.

`if(pg_fetch_assoc($var_name) == 'false')`

`pg_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array which you are comparing to a single string. Comparing mixed types is a complicated process in php, but in this case it knows that a string is not an array and so they aren't equal.

You probably want something like the following:

`$row = pg_fetch_assoc($var_name)
if ($row['ST_Intersects'] == false)`

Don't guess though, do something like `print_r($row)` to confirm you have the column-names and values you think you do.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The same query can return a different result every time you call it, since it's not deterministic. Any number of rows can qualify in each table, producing a Cartesian product of results. And since there is not unambiguous `ORDER BY` in your query, an arbitrary row will be the first to be returned.

Either add an `ORDER BY` (plus `LIMIT 1`) or more `WHERE` conditions to return a single row (deterministically).

Alternative query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   table_name p1
   JOIN   table_name p2 ON p1.id < p2.id
   WHERE  ST_Intersects(p1.column_name, p2.column_name)
   );
```

This returns exactly 1 row with `true` or `false` (never `null`, and never 0 or multiple rows). It's `true` if at least one combination intersects.

But also look to [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734959/939860) for the PHP part of the test.

Comment: there is a where condition in the query. At which place do you want me to add another where condition?

Comment: `WHERE p1.id < p2.id` is typically true for *many* rows. Your query is supposed to return a single result.

Comment: but here in this case my table has only two rows. even then the result is not as expected. is there any other way to do this for ex using case statement?

Comment: @briane: I added a query I would use.

Comment: your query gives correct result when used in postgresql. mine also giving correct result in postgresql.  But my problem is that how to use the 'true' and 'false' results of the query to echo 'accepted' or 'rejected'?